# keyboard show when selected time tapped long in datePicker(iPad)

Tags: swift, datepicker, textfield

In Swift, keyboard show when selected time(center time) tapped long in datePicker in UITableView Cell.
I want to hide keyboard on long tap, so please tell me how to write

the problem is below

[Problem Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRGHN.png)

I tried below code that create datePicker and set textField.inputView.
To write `textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()` and `textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()`, in ViewController keyboard don't show on long tap, but show in UITableViewCell.

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
datePicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "en")
datePicker.calendar = NSCalendar.current
datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels

textField.delegate = self
textField.inputView = datePicker
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
textField.tintColor = UIColor.clear
```

I tried codes that
`textField.inputView?.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()` and
`textField.inputView?.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()`, but problem did't solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. I add code below when set up UIDatePicker.

```
datePicker.rx.controlEvent(.editingDidBegin)
    .subsribe { _ in
        self.datePicker.resignFirstResponser()
    }
```